# Switching touch events to mouse events by using Chrome Extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension as panel in dev console for mobile interface testing and I need to pick elements (Similar to element picker in Dev Console) and process things according to picked element.

- User should be able to use responsive or any other mobile interface. Changing to a custom device does not work for me.
- I should be able to listen MouseEvents like mousemove instead of pointermove. Because, user should move mouse cursor over the site and catch elements as they move. Pointer events does not provide this.
- It would be also OK, if i could initialise The Element Picker programatically and listen events from it.
- I am not expecting someone to share a code sample. Check this API or naming correction is also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `chrome.debugger` API to send the same command devtools uses itself: [Overlay.setInspectMode](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Overlay/#method-setInspectMode).

Comment: I could not get it work properly but seems it is going in a good direction. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `protocol monitor` panel in devtools to see examples of the correct usage.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. I needed to send `Overlay.enable` command in order to pick but it does not work in model mode as expected. It keeps mobile features like Touch and make impossible to select. Event with the inspector